# What Woocommerce function is called on PayPal IPN response?

Tags: wordpress, paypal-ipn, woocommerce

I'm having a problem figuring out what function gets called when a payment is completed with Woocommerce and PayPal sends the IPN.

The IPN is being received because PayPal log file is being updated as soon as I click `Pay`, but I can't figure out what function is writing to that file.

I need to figure out if there is already a built in functionality to send emails to the admin **when** an order is created, and **where** this happens.

If it does exist I need to modify it to email other people too, and if not then I need to create it myself, but I need to know where to put the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checking the file `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/gateways/paypal/class-wc-paypal.php`, we see that there's an action hook inside the function `check_ipn_response`:

```
if ($this->check_ipn_request_is_valid()) :

    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

    do_action("valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request", $_POST);
```

You can hook into it like this:

```
add_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request', 'so_12967331_ipn_response', 10, 1 );

function so_12967331_ipn_response( $formdata )
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I had figured that out awhile ago, and if I remember correctly that is similar to what I did. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 5):

Building on @brasofilo's answer, I had to do extra work for each product for the current order.

*Note: I'm new to (un)serializing data, so I don't know why I had to unescape the double quotes to get `unserialize()` to work. It threw an error, otherwise. Maybe there's a better way to handle this.*

```
function so_12967331_ipn_response( $formdata ) {

    if ( !empty( $formdata['invoice'] ) && !empty( $formdata['custom'] ) ) {

        if( $formdata['payment_status'] == 'Completed' ) {

            if( is_serialized( $posted['custom'] ) ) {

                // backwards compatible
                // unserialize data
                $order_data = unserialize( str_replace('\"', '"', $posted['custom'] ) );
                $order_id = $order_data[0];

            } else {

                // custom data was changed to JSON at some point
                $order_data = (array)json_decode( $posted['custom'] );
                $order_id = $order_data['order_id'];

            }

            // get order
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            // got something to work with?
            if ( $order ) {

                // get user id
                $user_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );

                // get user data
                $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

                // get order items
                $items = $order->get_items();

                // loop thru each item
                foreach( $items as $order_item_id => $item ) {

                    $product = new WC_Product( $item['product_id'] );

                    // do extra work...

                }   
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the IPN request is accessible through $formdata can't I log it entirely to view what is inside without knowing what the array consists?

Comment: Is authorization involved while posting to the wc-api?